# How can I avoid the console output when assigning a value to a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, irb

Is it possible to escape that effect when assigning to a value:

```
irb(main):584:0>a = true
=>true
irb(main):584:0>
```

I have a code that has lots of assignings and when I am trying to test it I can not see the result because of all these returned values:

```
true
false
true
false
true
true
..
```

Comment: Wrap this code in proc object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can start the `irb` or console attaching the `--noecho` option.

```
$ irb --noecho
2.0.0p353 :001 > true
2.0.0p353 :002 >
```

Otherwise, if the console was started by another process, simply set `conf.echo = false`

```
$ irb 
2.0.0p353 :001 > true
 => true 
2.0.0p353 :002 > conf.echo = false
2.0.0p353 :004 > true
2.0.0p353 :005 >
```

Comment: I configured it aditionally with the conf.echo but it keeps on returning these values. I have a module that has few class and modules inside of it and in the end of the model I make instances of the nested class and it generates those values. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Type (or print out) `conf` and make sure that it prints out `conf.echo=false`. It also needs to be the first statement as soon as you start `irb`.

Answer (score 10):

Stick a semi-colon behind the command and it doesn't print, works for both pry and irb

### PRY

```
[1] pry(main)> a = true
=> true
[2] pry(main)> a = true;
[3] pry(main)>
```

### IRB

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > a = true
 => true
2.0.0p247 :002 > a = true;
2.0.0p247 :003 >
```

Comment: The IRB version does not do what you think it does. Try with this for example: `puts "hi";`. Your understanding of Pry behaviour is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above could work for my setup so I ended up just making a little helper and declared things out of scope. Quick and dirty, but gets the job done:

```
def quiet(&block)
  yield
  nil
end

foo = nil
quiet { foo = 'long' * 1000 }
```