# How to stop class initializer from printing object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, output, irb

Whenever I instantiate a new method from IRB it prints a bunch of stuff that I don't find necessary.  Is this expected behavior?  Can I stop it from happening?

For example, the following code

```
class Box
  def initialize(index)
    @index = index
  end
end

box = Box.new(5)
```

will print

```
 #<Box:0x000000015836e8 @index=5>
```

With more complicated stuff, I get a lot more in my terminal.

Answer (score 9):

This is expected, as by default `irb` prints out the result of the latest evaluation.

You can either [use `noecho`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731930/how-can-i-avoid-the-console-output-when-assigning-a-value-to-a-variable-in-ruby) or append `;nil` to print out `nil`.

```
box = Box.new(5); nil
```

Comment: Not having `irb` print this stuff out sort of defeats the purpose of a REPL.

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behavour. irb is a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (Read, Eval, Print Loop). This means that it will print the result of evaluating every consecutive expression that you entered. The result of calling the constructor of a class is the new object. Result of assignment is whatever was being assigned.

You can overwrite the `Object#inspect` method of your class to change what is being printed:

```
class Box
  def initialize(index)
    @index = index
  end

  def inspect
    "A box with index #{@index}"
  end
end

box = Box.new(5)

# => >A box with index 5
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.3.0 I get `(Object doesn't support #inspect)`.

Comment: Nvm, it's because I put the `inspect` method under `private`.